# Before element for toggle switch

Tags: html, css, absolute, bem

This is driving me slightly insane, so I would appreciate any help.

I'm trying to make a toggle switch that looks like there's a slab of colour underneath it that's only visible when the switch is on.

So when the switch is clicked it slides out to the right (add some margin-left) and then when clicked again it slides back. As things stand I've got two lis next to each other, both absolute position, one on top of the other. I'm moving the top one. But even when they're on top of each other, the green background of the bottom one is *slightly* visible. It's driving me mad. I've tried overflow: hidden on all of the elements.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="post-list">
    <li class="post-list__month">January</li>
    <li class="post-list__month--hidden"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    & li {
        height: 8rem;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    &__month {
        font-size: 3rem;

        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;

        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid rgba(99, 71, 151, 0);
        padding: 2rem;
        z-index: 1;

        &:hover {
            margin-left: 2rem;
            border: 1px solid rgba(99, 71, 151, 0.1);
        }


        &--hidden {
            background-color: green;
            height: 100%;
            width: 7rem;
            border: 1px solid rgba(99, 71, 151, 0);
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ez8mcjtw/

Comment: I think this is a normal behavior. Margin does not have any colour. It is just a margin to other elements. You cannot even set the margin colour, there is no such a thing. It means that whenever You set margin-left in Your example, Your green element is visible (previously covered by month). Month is on top because of z-index value.

Answer (score 1):

What you think about using a more semantic approach... like a simple checkbox? It does not require JavaScript to toggle states and can be used to pass data to the server if needed. Here is a simple snippet, tell me what you think :)

```css
.switch{
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: green;
}
.switch *{
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
} 
.switch__input{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.switch__text{
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 250ms;
}  
.switch__input:checked + .switch__text{
    margin-left: 30px; 
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="switch__input" value=""> 
    <span class="switch__text">Click me!</span>
</label>
```

Also on Codepen: https://codepen.io/niki_n14o/pen/eMoYZB

Comment: Glad I helped. Did you manage to integrate it in your project?